# How to return an array of nested items from every item of a parent object using AppSync?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am currently using Amplify with AppSync, and I want to **grab Bs from every A** **item** created, and populate them as an array of "items" as a result.

I searched up pipeline resolvers to deal with those, but got no luck since they are mostly based on "Grabbing all the Bs with A's ID=something", but what about ID=any.

I just want to follow the single-table architecture for DynamoDB.  In this sense, how am I able to grab all the Bs?

schema.graphql:

```
type A @model {
  id: String!
  theBs: [B]
}

type B {
  id: ID!
  A: String!
  name: String
}

type BConnection {
  items: [B]
  nextToken: String
}

type Query {
  getBs: BConnection
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the generated queries, it should be something like the following. You'll need to use the nextTokens to get everything.

That being said, this will perform a scan operation in DDB, which is slow and expensive.  I would recommend you read through [this article about access patterns](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/dataaccess) and see if there is a better way to organize your data.

```
query q {
      listA {
        nextToken
        items {
          theBs {
            nextToken
            items {
              id name
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: So in this case, would you favor multi-table design?  Since for this design, A also consist of B, C and D, and in the future I would need to list out B, C and D respectively.